# How to fetch and display child of subcategories in list page?

Tags: sidebar, filtered-nav

In list page above the narrow by list filter, I want to display the `subcategories` of the selected `category` to be displayed. The Code I use for that is:

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
?>

 <div class="block-content clearfix">
    <ul class="subcategories">
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>">
                    <span><?php echo $category->getName() ?>  </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But it is displaying only level1 subcategory. I want to display `level2` subcategory also. How to do that? Help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to display the subcategories and their subcategories In list page sidebar.
The code is below:

```
    <?php

$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())

 ?>
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>

    <div class="sidebar-block">
        <ul class="cat-list">
            <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
                <li class="category-li">
                 <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>">
                     <div class="main-cat" >  <?php echo $category->getName()?> </div>
                    </a>

                    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId()) ?>
                        <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                        <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                        <div class="sub-cat" style="display:none;">
                        <ul class="subcat-list">
                                    <?php foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```